# How to correctly handle WSAECONNABORTED in server code?

Tags: sockets, winsock

When a server receives a WSAECONNABORTED from a device (coming in from a `send()`), should a connection be re-established and data re-sent or should the server bail out and drop the connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is already dropped, there is nothing to bail from. And there is nothing you can  re-send on. Drop all state associated with connection, compensate any incomplete operation, return all resources to their pools, prepare for a new connection from a client.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks.

Another question then - is there a way to minimize this error or avoid it completely? It appears some clients will not re-establish a connection after this error, so this aborts the conversation completely.

Comment: How to minimize this or how to make the client reconnect is completely dependent on the code and application behavior.